# Xcode5 issue with xcodecolors plugin

Tags: xcode, plugins, xcode5, xcode5.1

I am in a big problem to recover my xcode 5,OS X 10.8.5.I have tried to install xcodecolors plugin in my xcode5 .When i did copy of that plugin to my xcode plugins folder it makes my xcode crash all the time.I tried the following things,
1.Cleared Cache
2.Deleted xcodecolors folder,plugins
3.Cleared Derived data folder
4.Deleted xcode and copied a new

But no luck..I am facing this issue since three days..

This is my crash report

```
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000018

VM Regions Near 0x18:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000101eba000-0000000101ebb000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Users/USER/Desktop/*/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5B1008

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff89f65498 objc_msgSend_vtable3 + 24
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ec4b2e7 -[NSBundle loadAndReturnError:] + 646
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ec4b05c -[NSBundle load] + 19
3   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010868cc10 -[XCPluginManager loadPluginBundle:] + 479
4   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010868c617 -[XCPluginManager findAndLoadPluginsInDomain:] + 4302
5   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010864fa88 XCInitializeCoreIfNeeded + 4247
6   com.apple.dt.IDE.Xcode3Core     0x00000001061d6270 +[Xcode3CoreInitializer ide_initializeWithOptions:error:] + 16
7   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000102a6f989 _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites + 1359
8   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000102a6f5ab _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites + 369
9   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000102a6f066 _IDEInitializePlugIns + 980
10  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000102a6eb55 __IDEInitialize_block_invoke + 42
11  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000102a6f270 IDESetSafeToLoadMobileDevice + 203
12  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000102ff6f04 -[IDEWelcomeWindowController _showFirstLaunchExperienceIfAppropriate] + 316
13  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010311d074 -[IDEWelcomeWindowController showFirstLaunchExperienceIfAppropriate] + 22
14  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010311cb3c -[IDEApplicationController _openFiles:] + 164
15  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010311ca82 -[IDEApplicationController application:openFiles:] + 61
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d2f5777 __69-[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenDocumentsForURLs:]_block_invoke_0 + 1674
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d3ea6c1 __78-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke_01437 + 143
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d0a817b -[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsWithCompletionHandler:] + 760
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d0a666e -[NSApplication _reopenWindowsAsNecessaryIncludingRestorableState:registeringAsReady:completionHandler:] + 298
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d2f5064 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenDocumentsForURLs:] + 306
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d0a6034 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 327
22  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ec3905b -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 308
23  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ec38ebd _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 106
24  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x00000001032350fe HandleOpenDocAE + 60
25  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8b59c078 aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*, unsigned int, unsigned char*) + 307
26  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8b59bed9 dispatchEventAndSendReply(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*) + 37
27  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8b59bd99 aeProcessAppleEvent + 318
28  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff887a7709 AEProcessAppleEvent + 100
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d0a2836 _DPSNextEvent + 1456
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d0a1df2 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
31  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x00000001025ba631 -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 84
32  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d0991a3 -[NSApplication run] + 517
33  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d03dbd6 NSApplicationMain + 869
34  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8b63d7e1 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8df16d16 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8f64adea _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 883
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8f64a9ee _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8df166d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f480f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f480ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f46b191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8df166d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f480f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f480ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f46b191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8df166d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f480f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f480ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f46b191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8df14686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8df13c42 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff86893233 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff86898916 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff868980e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ec0e526 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 356
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ec6c532 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f47e772 _pthread_start + 327
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f46b1a1 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8df166d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f480f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f480ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f46b191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8df166d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f480f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f480ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f46b191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8df166d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f480f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f480ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f46b191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8df166d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f480f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f480ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f46b191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8df16322 __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff868d7f46 __CFSocketManager + 1302
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f47e772 _pthread_start + 327
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f46b1a1 thread_start + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8df14686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8df13c42 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff86893233 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff86898916 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff868980e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
5   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x000000010c56f20e -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 162
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ec6c532 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f47e772 _pthread_start + 327
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f46b1a1 thread_start + 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Try codesign the plugin and then try copying it. It may solve the issue.

codesign -s bundleRoot

Also try to change the deployment target to 10.9 [ I saw this from this post https://github.com/neonichu/BBUDebuggerTuckAway/issues/9 ]